# nuxtjs / vuejs / nodejs, what to upload

Tags: vue.js, ftp

i'm new to node js, vuejs AND nuxtjs in the same times. I'm currently developping an application and my server is full. It seem that when i'm runing npm run build locally and just uploading .nuxt folder it's working well. am i doing this well ?

Answer (score 0):

For deploying you application there different steps available in the official docs. Here is the available options in [nuxt](https://nuxtjs.org/deployments/).

Also check this [commands and deployments](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/get-started/commands/) for nuxtjs.

**Server Deployment**

To deploy a SSR application we use target: 'server', where server is the default value.

`npm run build`

Nuxt will create a .nuxt directory with everything inside ready to be deployed on your server hosting.

Once your application is built you can use the start command to see a production version of your application.

`npm run start`

**Static Deployment (Pre-rendered)**

Nuxt gives you the ability to host your web application on any static hosting.

To deploy a static generated site make sure you have target: 'static' in your nuxt.config.js (for Nuxt >= 2.13):

```
// nuxt.config.js

export default {
  target: 'static'
}
```

`npm run generate`

Nuxt will create a dist/ directory with everything inside ready to be deployed on a static hosting service.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30371638)